# html scripts won't work after returning from jquery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I have simple html code (index.php) that calls a jquery post (function.php). This returns a value of HTML script. However this HTML script seems to not work with javascript anymore if returned by Jquery post.
 I just want this HTML script to be able to alert (sorry for the English).

```
//index.php 
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output">Display output</div>
    <div id="returnedpost"></div>


 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#output').click(function() {    
        $.ajax({ url: 'function.php',
             data: {action: ''
                    },
            type: 'POST',
             dataType: "html",
            success: function(output) {
              $("#returnedpost").html(output);
            }   
        }); //end of ajax

     }); //end of output click

     $("#alert").click(function(){
        alert('this is an alert');
     });
   }); //document.ready

 </script>
</body>

//function.php
<?php
 echo '<div id="alert">click me to alert</div>';
?>
```

As you can see, after clicking the "Display output" text, it will return an HTML text of "click me to alert". I just want this returned value to alert a message 'this is an alert' if being clicked.

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting listener there is no #alert yet.
You have to wait until data is loaded and then set click listener.

```
$('#output').click(function() {  
  const showPost = html => { //using es6 syntax
    document.getElementById('returnedpost').innerHTML = html;
    //#alert is created and now you can set listener
    document.getElementById('alert').addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert('this is an alert');
    });
  };  
  $.ajax({ url: 'function.php',
    data: {action: ''},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "html",
    success: showPost
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! You are very quick!